# Facebook Marketplace Data API?

Tags: facebook

I have a university project where for my thesis I would like to collect data on the rental market of my city, which a high volume of it is done through 4 or 5 open Facebook groups and the Facebook Marketplace (through people posting ads as posts and making deals in messenger).

I would like to know if there are any Facebook APIs that allow me access to the public posts of a specific Facebook group or the Facebook marketplace? I browsed their products website but I couldn’t find a suitable API.

Answer (score 3):

About the public posts of a specific Facebook group:
I also looked for that for a while. unfortunately, to be able to fetch the group's posts (even if the group is public) The admin of the group must add your app to the group. in other words, the admin must approve that

About the Facebook marketplace API:
Unfortunately, this one is even worse. there is just no API to retrieve marketplace data. I saw from the Facebook docs that there is a feature that is still a close program in beta.

sorry for the bad news but that's the case from my experience :/
If you do find another solution please share it